# How to run commands from different files discord.js

Tags: discord.js

So I am making a discord bot, and I want to run commands in different files. in my index I have

```
Fs.readdir("./commands/", (_err, files) => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
        if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
        let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
        client.commands.set(commandName, props);
        console.log(` Command loaded: ${commandName}`);
    });
});
```

And In my /commands/help.js I have

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

exports.run = async (client, message, args, prefix) => {
    
    if (args[0] == 'hi') {
        message.channel.send
    }
}
```

and it doesent do anything. In my console it says

```
� Command loaded: help
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong. Can you help?

Comment: Are you `command.execute()`ing the command?

Comment: You must send `!help hi` for it to do anything

Comment: I'm assuming your issue is where you are executing the command, that if you are executing it at all. Can you post your `message.js` (message event)?

Answer (score 1):

Although you are adding the command to the `client.commands` collection, you're never actually executing it. I'd recommend defining `module.exports` as an object with command details, as well as the actual function. For example:

---

#### `help.js`

```js
module.exports = {
 name: 'help',
 // any other details you might like, such as:
 description: 'See all the commands!',
 execute(client, message, args, prefix) {
  // the actual function

  if (args[0] == 'hi') {
   message.channel.send;
  }
 },
};
```

---

#### `index.js`

```js
Fs.readdir('./commands/', (_err, files) => {
 files.forEach((file) => {
  if (!file.endsWith('.js')) return;
  let command = require(`./commands/${file}`); // access all details though this variable
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
  console.log(` Command loaded: ${command.name}`);
 });
});
```

---

In your `message` event, when you want to trigger your command:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 // your code

 // get the command and execute the function
 client.commands.get('Command Name').execute(client, message, args, prefix);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not sending anything when you use the help command, you should have it like this:

```js
if(args[0] == 'hi') {
  message.channel.send('Hello!');
}
```